# Initializing a variable as global versus local gives different results (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, nested, global-variables

I have a question about initializing a variable as a global versus local variable.  I got different results for variable sum as a global variable (output: 16) versus sum as a local variable inside helper function dfs (output: 10). Does it have something to do with recursive nature?

I am calculating sum as the running total of each integer multiply by its depth in the nested array.

The test case is [[1,1],2,[1,1]]
The correct answer for the sum is 10.

Why does the first method, declaring a global variable, is wrong in this case?  What is the best practice?

```
//global variable 

let sum = 0
function dfs(nestedList, depth){
    
    for(let i=0; i<nestedList.length; i++){
        if(nestedList[i].isInteger()) {
            sum += nestedList[i].getInteger()*depth
        }
        else {
           sum += dfs(nestedList[i].getList(),depth+1)
        }
    }
   return sum
    
}

var depthSum = function(nestedList) {
    console.log(sum)
    return dfs(nestedList,1)
};
```

```
local variable


function dfs(nestedList, depth){
    let sum = 0
    for(let i=0; i<nestedList.length; i++){
        if(nestedList[i].isInteger()) {
            sum += nestedList[i].getInteger()*depth
        }
        else {
           sum += dfs(nestedList[i].getList(),depth+1)
        }
    }
   return sum
    
}

var depthSum = function(nestedList) {
    console.log(sum)
    return dfs(nestedList,1)
};
```

Comment: If the variable is global, it exists only once for your whole program. If it's local, it exists once for each invocation of `dfs`. So also when `dfs` calls itself, the inner "instances" will see an entirely new, private `sum` variable each time, accessible only to themselves. With the global variable you mix up all the calculations and add some stuff twice. Best practice is _always_ local.

Comment: Neither version should work. There's no `return` statement anywhere.

Comment: Is there supposed to be `return sum;` at the end of each function?

Comment: It depends what you achieving, also local variable console log it goes to you wrong way because you cant access sum value from outside, if you see some value it means you should define some where in as globaly

Comment: With the global version you have the side effect that the second time around you use it for some other structure it will add to the previous run. I agree with Barmar that none of these work since both `dfs` return `undefined` so `depthSum` will also return `undefiend` in addition to the local version will not have `sum` available for `console.log`

Comment: Barmar is right, I missed the return statement in dfs function.  Thank you for the recommendation to keep the variable local CherryDT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style typically yields the best results. Below we see `dfs` as a pure expression. Concerns about global scope, intermediate state, and side effects disappear!

```js
const dfs = (t = [], d = 0) =>
  Array.isArray(t)
    ? t.reduce((r, v) => r + dfs(v, d + 1), 0)
    : t * d
    
console.log(dfs([[1,1],2,[1,1]]))
// (1*2 + 1*2 + 2*1 + 1*2 + 1*2)
// 10 

console.log(dfs([1,[2,[3,[4]]]]))
// (1*1 + 2*2 + 3*3 + 4*4)
// 30
```

Comment: Excellent way of eliminating side effects. @Thank you for showing how to use recursion with the reduce method.